# Can I use SQLExpress as the server in sync framework 4.0?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I would like to use sqlexpress on the server end for ease of development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql Server, Sql Express and Sql Azure uses the same provider SqlSyncProvider in Sync Framework so i dont see any reason why you cant use Sql Express as the server provider.

btw, please note that Sync Fx v4 RTM has been put on hold, see: [Sync Framework V4 Update](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/synclab/thread/2c6f1ab8-fed4-4c43-9a55-93002a9a8e02)